# How to make Navigation Drawer stay on for every action in Navigation Graph

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, androidx

I have created a NavigationDrawer on the MainActivity with NavigationGraph.

[image: This is what the MainActivity looks like][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn4C5.png)

When I select the settings button the Navigation navigates an action_home_fragment_to_settings_fragment. But there's a back button on top of the action bar.

[image: This is what the app looks like after navigating to settings fragment][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqf3r.png)

How to set the navigation drawer persistent no matter what action or fragment to navigate?

Comment: make them top level destinations. see appbar configuration https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#kotlin

Comment: @Raghunandan I added those fragments as top level destination. Now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Raghunandan One more help please. I have a custom layout inside NavigationView. I have provided OnClickListeners for the buttons in the custom view from MainActivity. Then should I create actions for navigating to other top level destinations from each top level destination. Or do we have a simple option or something.